# Twisted Server/iOS Client sending and receiving images

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, twisted, nsdata

I'm trying to send an image to the twisted server and back to my iPhone.  My code works on the simulator but does not work on the iPhone.  I have no idea why.  All I'm doing is sending the data for the image to the server and then immediately back to my iPhone.  Here is the relevant code that I'm using.

---

SERVER SIDE:

---

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        #self.transport.write("""connected""")
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "clients are ", self.factory.clients
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        #print "data is ", data
        self.transport.write(data);
    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
print "Server Started"
reactor.run()
```

---

CLIENT SIDE:

---

```
@interface LoginScreen : UIViewController <NSStreamDelegate> {
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *outputData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *testImage;


@implementation LoginScreen : UIViewController
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"avis-mbp", 80, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
    switch (streamEvent) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            if (theStream == inputStream) {
                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                long len;
                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0) {
                        NSData *output = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len];
                        if (nil != output) {
                            [self.appDel.outputData appendBytes:buffer length:len];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            NSLog(@"Event Ended");
            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            theStream = nil;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(IBAction)runNetworkingTest:(id)sender {
    [self initNetworkCommunication];
    NSData *pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"shalin.jpg"]);
    NSMutableData *mutedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:pictureData];
    [outputStream write:[mutedData bytes] maxLength:[mutedData length]];
}

-(IBAction)testPicture:(id)sender {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.outputData];
    self.testImage.image = image
}
```

Comment: We are going to need a bit more than not working. What data are you getting? Any errors?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I completely forgot to specify the error.  It is displaying about half of the image, but the rest of it is black.

Comment: I counted the bytes in each instance and found that when I run it on the simulator it transfers 244216 bytes over but on the iPhone it only transfers 131768.  Clearly that's the problem, but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I think I solved it.  I wasn't handling the writing aspect of the stream.  I needed to address the NSStreamHasSpaceAvailable case.

Comment: can you please post your solution as an answer for posterity?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to my problem.  It had to do with the space available when writing to the server.  The iPhone can only write a specific amount of bytes at a time, so I had to regulate the amount of data that was written in the delegate via the NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable case.  Here is the missing piece of code that will allow you to write an image to the server and read it back to the client via a TCP connection to a twisted server:

---

Missing Code to be put in the NSStream Delegate

---

```
case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
        {
            if (self.appDel.willWrite && [self.appDel.inputData length] != 0) {
                int bufferSize = 1024;
                if ([self.appDel.inputData length] > bufferSize){
                    NSData *sendData = [self.appDel.inputData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, bufferSize)];
                    self.appDel.inputData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[self.appDel.inputData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(bufferSize, [self.appDel.inputData length] - bufferSize)]];
                    [outputStream write:[sendData bytes] maxLength:[sendData length]];
                } else {
                    [outputStream write:[self.appDel.inputData bytes] maxLength:[self.appDel.inputData length]];
                    self.appDel.inputData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

                }
            }
        }
```

---

Modified version of the run networking test

---

```
-(IBAction)runNetworkingTest:(id)sender {
    [self initNetworkCommunication];
    self.appDel.willWrite = YES;
    NSData *pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"shalin.jpg"]);
    [self.appDel.inputData appendData:pictureData];
}
```

---

Code to display the image

---

```
-(IBAction)showNetworkingArray:(id)sender {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.appDel.outputData];
    self.testImage.image = image;
}
```

---

Notice:  I am writing 1024 bytes at a time.  IT WILL NOT WORK IF YOU WRITE TOO MANY BYTES AT A TIME.  For example, I tried 1024 * 8 and that did not work with a single image.  However, when I set the buffer size to be 1024, I was able to send about ten images over without a problem.